# How to adapt my testresults to xunit-format

Tags: xml, xunit

at work we have some automated testing, which is performed during the night and then summarized in a specific XML-format.
The next idea was to import these results into Polarion, which however accepts only xUnit formatted results. This is where I am stuck - I just can't seem to find a correct explanation on how I should change my own XML format to make it look like xUnit?
Here is how my results currently look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="report.xsl"?>
<TestRun Date="2012_08_06__15_08  (y_m_d__h_m)" Plattform="WinCE" Name="GCA-Testrun" GCA-Version="V5.03.02">
<TestSuite Name="Systemtest" Container="GCA">
    <FailedTests>
        <FailedTest Name="test14877_1.lua" Data="">
            <Item>
                <FailureType>Failure</FailureType>
                <Location>
                    <File></File>
                    <Line></Line>
                </Location>
                <Message>setErrorAndExit : Failed!</Message>
            </Item>
            <elTime>777.00</elTime>
            <execTime>0h12min57s</execTime>
            <Testnumber>Undefined</Testnumber>
        </FailedTest>
    </FailedTests>
    <SuccessfulTests>
        <SuccessfulTest Name="test15414.lua" Testnumber="Undefined" Data="" elTime="684.00" execTime="0h11min24s" />
    </SuccessfulTests>
</TestSuite>
```

I only need the testrun-name and the tag successful or failed.